# MST-related algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Given an undirected and connected graph `G(V,E)` with weight function `w:E->R`, an edge `e(u,v)` belongs to E. Which algorithm that runs in linear run-time complexity can assure if there's a minimal spanning tree that contains the edge e?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform depth-first search starting from **u** and ignoring any edge with weight equal to weight of given edge or heavier. If DFS completes without visiting **v**, this means there is no cycle where given edge is the heaviest edge, therefore given edge is contained in some minimal spanning tree.

Answer (score 2):

This is asking you to implement [Prim's Minimum Spanning Tree](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/graph/mst) twice.

- The first time run the algorithm as normal. Make a note of the weight of the mst.
- The second time, instead of starting with an empty tree as Prim's algorithm normally does, start with the nodes u and v already on the tree -- which is the same as having edge e(u,v). Then continue building the mst.
- at the end if the second mst is the same weight as the first mst, then edge e(u,v) can be in a mst. If not, there is a lighter mst.

By the way, 2*O(n) is still O(n)